# Non-equality with Gamma functions

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, factorial, gamma-function

Let $n \in N$, $k \in Z_+$.

Show that
$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac 12\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac 32\right)}\neq\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}\pi^{1-\frac n2}.
$$

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried Stirling's formula, but it doesn't help much...

Comment: You could use the definition of the Gamma function. There are a few simplistic identities which are apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things on learns about [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is its  functional equation
$$z\,\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1),\quad z\in\mathbb C$$
With it, your problem reduces to 
$$\frac{1}{k+\frac 12} \neq\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}\pi^{1-\frac n2}.$$
Also, multiplying both sides by $\Gamma\left(k+\frac{n-2}{2}\right)^2$ and using the [duplication formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) we get 
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{n-2}{2}\right)^2}{k+\frac 12} \neq
2^{1-(2k+n-2)} \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(2k+n-2)  \pi^{1-\frac n2}.$$
The squared $\Gamma$ on the left is a rational multiple of $\pi$. On the right there is a rational multiple of $\pi^{(3-n)/2}$. So, $n$ must be equal to $1$. Write out $\Gamma(k-1/2)^2$ and compare two sides.